# How to call a function in vba which is already assigned to a button

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to create a ribbon in excel and I was successful. Now I have assigned a macro to a button.

```
Function delete_cells(control As IRibbonControl)
```

Now, I created another macro, from which I need to call the function `delete_cells`. I tried to call it as below.

```
Function modify_cells(control As IRibbonControl)
delete_cells
End Sub
```

I am getting an error saying *Argument not optional*. Please help me with this error.

Comment: You `Function` requires `control` argument. You need to supply it like this: `delete_cells control`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest that you create a separate subroutine that you call from the button's OnAction and anywhere else you want to call it from, e.g.:

```
'button macro
Sub cmdDeleteCells_OnAction(control as iRibbonControl)
DeleteCells
End Sub

'another Sub that calls the delete routine
Sub SomeOtherSub
DeleteCells
End Sub

'the one they're all talking about
Sub DeleteCells
msgbox "All your cells are toast, bwah hah hah ha!"
End Sub
```

EDIT: If you really want to just call the button's OnAction sub, you need to pass it an iRibbonControl object as well, so declare a fake one:

```
Sub CallTheButtonsCode()
Dim FakeControl As IRibbonControl

cmdDeleteCells_OnAction FakeControl
End Sub
```

I really don't recommend this for code maintenance reasons, but it works.

Comment: Doug Glancy,
Right now i using the method which you suggested. But I want to know if there is a way without using that extra Sub.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Function delete_cells(control As IRibbonControl)` you have an REQUIRED argument `...(control As IRibbonControl)`. When you call the function it should look like this :

```
Function modify_cells(control As IRibbonControl)
delete_cells(myControl) 'myControl is your variable. Define what control you want to pass to the function.
End Sub
```

Comment: Since I am new to vba, I don't know much about controls. So what kind of control should I pass to the function delete_cells ? I just want to execute the function delete_cells which I press the button specified for modify_cells.

Comment: I would recommend using the suggestion from @Doug Glancy.
If you want to get rid of extra sub, you can paste the code directly into all procedures, from where you want to run the code, but that is not a good practice I think.
The `Sub SomeOtherSub DeleteCells End Sub` Doug was talking about is not necessary, you don't need it at all. It was just a demonstration, that you can call the `DeleteCells` from different places.